# Remove seconds from an API reply using java

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

> In the code below. String str; is a reply from an API. So I cant change it. But I want to remove the seconds part from that. Otherwise I'll have to send a request to that API every single second to keep my Time widget updated. I also contacted the API developers if there is any parameter to get timestamp in a specific format. They said no.

```
Main() {
    //assume that timestamp reply from the API is being stored in 'str'
    //now we've to remove :55 from str
    String str = "Mon, 18 Mar 2019 03:43:55 GMT";
    Date date=null;
    try {
        date=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm z").parse(str);
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> Getting an exception: Unparseable date

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon, 18 Mar 2019 03:43:55 GMT"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at Main.<init>(Main.java:9)
at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

> API's Support team reply:
>
> This isn't really a question about geocoding, but there are two ways you could parse the date.
>   1. use a regular expression. 
>   2. you might have noticed in the "timestamp" section there is also a created_unix which contains a unixtime.
>   I have no idea which programming language you are using, but I am sure there are standard modules for converting unixtime to whatever format you would like

Comment: Are you looking to _truncate_ a date to the nearest minute, or is this concern just a presentation thing in the string itself?

Comment: You have to parse with `HH:mm:ss`, but then `date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)`, perhaps?

Comment: You could either search for the last ':' and remove it and the following two digits, or you could parse the string using a pattern that includes the seconds, then generate a string with a pattern that excludes the seconds.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), specifically `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`.

Comment: It’s not clear what you really need, so hard to guide you correctly. I don’t think modifying the string will save you from calling every second, please explain. And explain what more precisely you will be using the modified string for. Would a string like `18/03/19, 3:43 AM` (without seconds) be suitable? Now we’re at it, do you want it in your own time zone rather than in GMT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if your end goal is to actually generate a date object with the seconds component removed, or if you just want to change the presentation of your timestamp to remove the seconds component.  For the latter requirement, a simple regex replacement can work here:

```
String str = "Mon, 18 Mar 2019 03:43:55 GMT";
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\d):\\d{2}(?=\\s)", "");
System.out.println(str);

Mon, 18 Mar 2019 03:43 GMT
```

Comment: I just want to output the date and time on my javafx scene.

Comment: This solved my problem. Actually this is what the API support team suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work for this example; I don't know if you want a generic version for any timestamp--that would be possible but a bit more complicated.

```
Main() {
    //assume that timestamp reply from the API is being stored in 'str'
    //now we've to remove :55 from str
    String str = "Mon, 18 Mar 2019 03:43:55 GMT";
    str = str.replace(":55", "");

    Date date=null;
    try {
        date=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm z").parse(str);
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Sorry. This won't help. As ":55" is changing every second. It doesn't have to be ":55" always.

Comment: OK, looks like you got your answer using regex above.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time and a proper datetime object rather than a string

Internally in your program don’t represent a point in time as a string. Use a proper date-time object. Parse the string to obtain one:

```
    String str = "Mon, 18 Mar 2019 03:43:55 GMT";

    // Parse for internal use
    Instant when = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.parse(str, Instant::from);
    System.out.println(when);
```

> 2019-03-18T03:43:55Z

The string you’ve got from the API is in the standard RFC 1123 / RFC 822 format (which includes seconds, and they are correct in not accepting to break the standard (though the ISO 8601 format might have been even more appropriate)). A parser for RFC 1123 / RFC 822 format is built into java.time, saving us from constructing it ourselves from a format pattern string.

I have assumed that the point in time is the important information here and have thrown away the information that it was transmitted in GMT (the same happened in your code in the question). If the offset is worth preserving, we need an `OffsetDateTime`instead of an `Instant`, and the same built-in formatter still works:

```
    OffsetDateTime whenWithOffset
            = OffsetDateTime.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);
    System.out.println(whenWithOffset);
```

> 2019-03-18T03:43:55Z

The trailing `Z` in the output means UTC, which is *practically* the same as GMT (the theoretical difference is less than a second).

I suggest that the seconds you asked about will not do any harm in your program. I am assuming that you only want to avoid presenting them to your user. In case I am wrong, removing the seconds is easy when you know how:

```
    Instant when = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.parse(str, Instant::from)
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
```

> 2019-03-18T03:43:00Z

Now the seconds are set to 0. `truncatedTo` can be used in the same way with an `OffsetDateTime`.

### Present to the user in the user’s time zone and locale and without seconds

I suggest that your user would like to see the date and time without seconds in his or her own time zone and in a format that is customary in his or her culture. For example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                    .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-IN"));
    ZonedDateTime whenInUsersTimeZone = when.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
    String formatted = whenInUsersTimeZone.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(formatted);
```

> 18/03/19, 9:13 AM

You notice:

- The time has been converted from 03:43 (GMT) to 09:13 (India Standard Time).
- Even though the time in your program contains seconds, they are not displayed.

If you want to use the JVM’s default formatting locale, use `.withLocale(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT))` (leaving out this part completely works too, but I prefer making it explicit that we are relying on the default). If you want to use the default time zone, use `when.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())`.

### Avoid Date and SimpleDateFormat

The date-time classes that you used, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. I find it so much nicer to work with.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.